# TinyMCE Custom Image Upload Modal

Tags: angular, tinymce-6

We are looking to use TinyMCE 6 as a rich text editor in an Angular 14 application.

As part of uploading an image, we need to be able to open a custom Angular/Material modal dialog component instead of the usual file picker, when the "Browse for an image" button is selected.

[image]

Is there a way to access an event when the "Browse for an image" button is used?